# How to get images(same name) from different drawable folder in a android project?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image

I need to get same images with same name, but in different resolution. So i created different drawable folder for every resolution and having images with same name in all folder. But when i am running this aap at that time some images coming dynamically at diff resolution. I have to bound images, should comes from related resolution folder at which device it is running at that moment. I used some images as theme, these are making trouble for me. :( :(

I created drawable folder in this way.

drawable-sw600dp-land-mdpi.
drawable-sw600dp-port-mdpi.

Please help me, I am indeed.

Comment: You don't need to pass images to your view dynamically. Android will automatically take it from one of supported drawable directory.

Comment: Yes u r right, We don't need to pass images dynamically. I am also not passing them dynamically. But it is not working Sir. I searched a lot of tuts and android.developers blog also but not getting it.

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your folders are named correctly, android will take care of that by hisself. If the device is rotated, the activity is destroyed and recreated again. Depending on on current state (landscape or portrait), android loads the drawable from the corresponding folder and you only have to say "load a drawable" :)

If the corresponding folder doesnt exist, android falls back to a default one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

"drawable-sw600dp-land-mdpi" to "drawable-sw600dp-land"
"drawable-sw600dp-port-mdpi" to "drawable-sw600dp-port".

Remove "mdpi" from directory names.

Answer (score 0):

create drawable folder like this

```
  drwable-land-mdpi
 drawable-port-mdpi

  drwable-land-hdpi
  drawable-port-hdpi
```

and also see this link [google resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2)